# Function plus asterisk in select in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an `Flask-SQLAlchemy` program in Python with [declarative](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/) extension in use.

I have an SQL query like this:

```
select *, max(column_1) from table_name group by column_2
```

How can I translate it to a query using `SQLAlchemy`?

`column_1` is an integer field, totally independent from `column_2`, that is a foreign key from other table.

I know I have [max function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.max) and I tried things like this:

```
result = session.query(func.max(table_name.column_name_1)).group_by(table_name.column_name_2)
```

But I'm not getting proper results.

Comment: `session.query(table_name, func.max(...))`, given that `table_name` is a declarative model class, as it would seem to be. But are you sure you should be doing that? Does `column_name_2` [functionally determine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) the rest?

Comment: @IljaEverilä you are right, his is a declarative model, I will update my question. I don't know exactly, the answer to the second question. let my edit my question first to give more info.

Comment: @IljaEverilä it seems that your comment creates the proper query, but the result object is not properly mapped to the entity it maps. I got strange results

Comment: Which DB are you using? I'm pretty sure Postgresql for example would not allow that query to execute, because from your description it'd seem that the set of columns that you group by does not determine all the columns. Put another way there are many different values for `*`, given the grouping `table_name.column_name_2`. Some databases allow you to perform such a query and pick values from an unspecified row in the group. Perhaps you should select `table_name.column_name_2, func.max(...)` in a subquery and join against `table_name` using `column_name_2`. Or you could use a window function.

Comment: I'm using SQLite. the `results` object contained two elements per item in a list. finally I got the answer using a map in Python: `results = session.query(table_name, func.max(table_name.column_1)).group_by(table_name.column_2).all() \ list(map(lambda x: x[0], results))`. the perfect answer would offer this result using library idioms. I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: Why are you discarding the maximum value? Are you perhaps actually looking for how to get the [tag:greatest-n-per-group], or the row with the largest `table_name.column_name_1` value in a group.

Comment: I want to have exactly a result that can be mapped to the entity representing that table. for that reason I need to discard the max value. so I want the maximum column_1 per each unique column_2 (which is an ID, foreign key). I was able to get the SQL query but I wanted an `SQLAlchemy` idiom with proper mapped result for the ORM.